# Efficiently search two-tuple

Tags: python, tuples

What's the best one-liner replacement for the code below? I'm sure there's a smarter way.

```
choices = ((1, 'ONE'), (2, 'TWO'), (3, 'THREE'))
some_int = 2
for choice in choices:
    if choice[0] == some_int:
        label = choice[1]
        break;
# label == 'TWO'
```

Comment: What happens if some `choice[0]` appears twice?  Do you want the first or last?  Note that the `dict(choices)` approach will use the last - `dict(reversed(choices))` will give the first if that matters.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
labels = dict(choices)
label = labels[some_int]
```

you could, of course, join this into an one-liner, if you don't need `labels` anywhere else.

Answer (score 6):

You could use a dict.

```
>>> choices = { 1: 'ONE', 2: 'TWO', 3: 'THREE' }
>>> label = choices[2]
>>> label
'TWO'
```

Comment: The data structure is a two-tuple since that's how you define field choices in Django.

Answer (score 5):

For a one-off search, if you're committed to starting with that data structure and can't amortize the time it takes to build it into a dictionary, and don't know whether the starting structure is sorted (so that bisection-search is not an option), there are no substantially faster algorithms than simple linear search.  You can express it elegantly, e.g. in Python 2.6 or better:

```
label = next((lab for cho, lab in choices if cho==someint), None)
```

assuming you want the label to be `None` if no choice matches -- or if you want an exception to be raised in that case, just

```
label = next(lab for cho, lab in choices if cho==someint)
```

or in older Python versions

```
label = (lab for cho, lab in choices if cho==someint).next()
```

but I doubt performance will change much (easy to measure with `timeit` if you care, but in that case you need to provide some realistic examples of `choices` -- typical lengths, chance of no choice being acceptable, etc, etc).

Answer (score 3):

If you're really looking for a one liner...

```
label = dict(choices)[some_int]
```

that is,

```
>>> choices = ((1, 'ONE'), (2, 'TWO'), (3, 'THREE'))
>>> dict(choices)[1]
'ONE'
```